# Android TransitionManager Views below not animated

Tags: android, transition, android-cardview

[ScreenRecording](https://imgur.com/a/e16P2X5)

I like the animation of the cardView at the top, but the views below arent animated and just snap in place. How can I animate them in a way that there is no overlapping? This is not a recyclerView, these are individual cardViews.

**Code for the CardView at the top:**

```
imageViewMuellExtend = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMuellExtend);
    imageViewMuellExtend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            muell_extend = (ConstraintLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.muell_extend);
            cardViewMuell = (CardView) root.findViewById(R.id.cardViewMuell);

            if(muell_extend.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardViewMuell, new AutoTransition());
                muell_extend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageViewMuellExtend.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp);
            } else {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardViewMuell, new AutoTransition());
                muell_extend.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageViewMuellExtend.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp);
            }
        }
    });
```

**XML Layout of the CardView:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewMuell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewMuellIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text="Müll"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewMuellIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageViewMuellIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewMuellIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewMuellExtend"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewMuellIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewMuellIcon" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/muell_extend"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewMuellIcon">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/info_muell"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Every CardView in this Fragment looks like this and the items are just renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument you're passing into `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` is the `sceneRoot`. The transition will only affect views inside `sceneRoot`, nothing outside of it.

You're passing `cardViewMuell` as this argument, meaning the transition will animate views inside the clicked card, but none of the other cards. Try passing a `sceneRoot` that contains all of the cards.

Comment: Thanks replacing cardViewMuell with the parent worked!